# how to replace a character with " + " in java?

Tags: java, recursion

So I'm trying to make a program that will write a number in expanded form (ex. when the input is 12 the result would be 10 + 2)

I used recursion to solve this problem. I Think I have the code down, which works to print out the actual numbers and all I need to do is return a string with a " + " in between every 0 and [1-9] integer. so that I can go from "102" to "10 + 2"

the problem is when I try

```
replaceAll("(0)([1-9])", "$1 + $2");
```

I get an infinite recursion problem that I cannot pinpoint why this happens. but this does not happen with literally any other input.

for example if I were to do

```
replaceAll("(0)([1-9])", "$1 - $2");
```

It would work perfectly. It would return "10 - 2"

heck even

```
replaceAll("(0)([1-9])", "$1 +  $2");
```

works just as intended because of the extra space and returns "10 +  2"

I have no idea why the only input that doesn't work is "$1 + $2" someone please help I am going insane.

```
public class Kata
{
    public static String expandedForm(int num)
    {
      int i = 0;
      int x = 0;
      int withZeros = 0;
      if (num <= 0) {
        return "";
      }
      
        for(i = String.valueOf(num).length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
          x = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(num).charAt(i)));
        
          if (x != 0) {
            break;
          }
        }
       
        
        if (i == String.valueOf(num).length() - 1) {
          withZeros = x;
        }
        else {
           withZeros = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(num).charAt(i))) * 
              ((String.valueOf(num).length() - (i+1)) * 10);
            
        }
      
          
      String result = (expandedForm(num - withZeros) + withZeros).replaceAll("(0)([1-9])", "$1 + $2");
      
      
      
      
    
      return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use recursion and regular expressions for this? Personally I'd go in an entirely different direction. It feels like it's simple to split the string into digits, and you know from the index how many trailing zeroes are needed for each digit. Ignore digits which are themselves zero, and just concatenate each part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why your regex replacement approach should be causing any errors.  Consider:

```java
String input = "102";
String output = input.replaceAll("0([1-9])", "0 + $1");
System.out.println(output);  // 10 + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is converting int to expanded form, I suggest using simple for loop instead of recursion:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input = 102;
        System.out.println(expandedForm(102));  
    }
    
    public static String expandedForm(int num) {
        String str = String.valueOf(num);
        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = ch.length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
            if(ch[i] != '0') {
                int n = Integer.valueOf(ch[i] - '0') * (int)Math.pow(10, j);
                list.add(String.valueOf(n));
            }
        }
        
        Collections.reverse(list);
        
        return String.join(" + ", list);
    }
}
```

[OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/W1vMzSIx_)